# uninstall SRWare Iron browser

Tags: software-uninstall

I installed SRWare iron browser through the command line. Now I want to remove it. I see that the command to remove software is 
sudo apt-get remove .

I have tried `iron.deb`, `iron64.deb`, `iron`, `srware` but it says these are not found. I tried to remove it from the list of installed apps, but it does not appear there. Can someone please tell me what the app name is so I can remove it properly.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your distro name, its version, the source of the browser, its version and the exact command you use to install this browser. How do you generate "the list of install apps"?

Answer (score 1):

`grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log`  will output a list of recently installed packages by time of installation.

After finding the name of the package, proceed with  `sudo apt-get remove` as you described.